# What is the scala equivalent of Set in java?

Tags: scala

Which type in scala can be the equivalent of Set in java? Is Set or List, or something else? 
I think Seq might be the correct answer, but I need to use collectFirst method, can anyone help me with that?

Comment: `Set`? Let us know what you want to do with the data structure or we can't really help.

Comment: There's plenty of sets in java, choose set you really need: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-in-java/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) documents `Set` conversions like so

```
scala.collection.mutable.Set <=> java.util.Set  // two-wayconversion via asScala and asJava 
scala.collection.Set          => java.util.Set  // one-way conversion via asJava
```